# Domain of `Sqrt[x]^2`

Tags: core-language

I'm just starting to work with Mathematica and this is simplified version of the problem I have: seems that `Sqrt[x]^2` simplifies to just `x` without any restrictions on domain:

```
In[1]:= FunctionDomain[Sqrt[x]^2, x]
Out[1]:= True
```

I can't restrict `x>=0` globally because negative `x` is necessary in other parts of my calculation.

Is there a (preferably automatic) way to propagate domain during function composition?

So far I tried `Sqrt`, entering square root using Ctrl+2, and explicitly creating composition like this:

```
In[2]:= f[x_] := Sqrt[x]
        g[a_] := a^2
        z[p_] := Composition[g, f]
        FunctionDomain[z[x], x]
Out[2]:= True
```

[image]

Comment: `Sqrt`'s domain is at least the entire real line because _Mathematica_ automatically uses complex numbers as relevant. If you would like to ensure that the real roots are used, consider looking at `Surd`.

Comment: For negative values: `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Sqrt[x]], x < 0]` gives `I*(x^2)^(1/4)`, and `FullSimplify[%^2, x < 0]` is `x`, that corresponds to your plot.

Comment: @eyorble when I run FunctionDomain[Sqrt[x]] it produces {x>=0}

Comment: @Alx `Sqrt` is not the best example. Consider (x+2)*(x+1)/(x+2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Sqrt[x]^2` evaluates to `x`:

```
Sqrt[x]^2
```

> x

Hence,  your call to [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain) checks the domain of `x`. You can use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated) to prevent this:

```
FunctionDomain[Unevaluated[Sqrt[x]^2], x]
```

> x >= 0

Comment: Thanks Carl that is what I was looking for.